# How to disable macOS Monterrey's new Safari tab style

Tags: safari, beta, monterey

How to disable macOS Monterrey's new Safari tab style and return to the previous style?

What Safari tabs look like in macOS Monterrey

[image: mont]

What Safari tabs look like in macOS Big Sur

[image: bigs]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it's possible to make it as it was originally. Otherwise an update would theoretically make no sense. As far as I know, Apple does not implement outdated things in an update when they are renewed.

Comment: ...Also as this is a developer beta these things may change. As the developer Beta is available only to people with Apple Developer accounts, you can log into the developer.apple.com and provide feedback on Safari and how and why you think that it should be reverted or a switch offered to revert the changes for some people. But as a developer you need the latest build with all if it's foibles to test your software against.

Comment: Use another browser whose tab style you prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to return to the previous style.

macOS 12, aka Monterey, is currently in developer [preview](https://www.apple.com/macos/monterey-preview/). Please use the included [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) to let Apple know your opinion about the new style.